# Como remover parênteses rectos de um array em scala

Tags: scala, cassandra

Eu tenho um array de datas [2014-11-08 06:27:00.0], e gostaria de remover os parênteses rectos 2014-11-08 06:27:00.0.

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").setAppName("CasteDate").setMaster("local[*]")
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
   .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
   .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val csc=new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

var input: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
input.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
var dia: SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
var mes: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM")
var ano: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
var horas: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH")
var minutos: SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("mm")

val data=csc.sql("SELECT timecol from smartgrids.analyzer_temp").collect()

import sqlContext.implicits._

val result = data.map(row => {
                         val day = dia.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val month = mes.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val year = ano.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val hour = horas.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val minute = minutos.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                             })

val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("day", 2), ("month", 2), ("year", 4), ("hour", 2), ("minute", 2)))
collection.saveToCassandra("features", "datepart", SomeColumns("day", "month", "year", "hour", "minute"))
sc.stop()
```

Depois de executar o código eu recebo o erro:

```
   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "[2015-08-20 21:01:00.0]" 
   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

Eu penso que erro seja porque estou a mapear a data com os parênteses rectos, por esta razão queria remove-lo. 
Aguém consegue ajudar-me por favor?

Comment: voce tem a certeza que só um valor de data q é retornado do banco de dados?

Comment: vc tem uma lista assim: `([2014-11-08 06:27:00.0] [2014-11-08 06:27:00.0] [2014-11-08 06:27:00.0])` ou assim: `[2014-11-08 06:27:00.0] [2014-11-08 06:27:00.0] [2014-11-08 06:27:00.0]` ?

Comment: quando eu executo o código é retornado um array assim: Array([2015-08-20 21:01:00.0], [2014-11-07 12:22:00.0],06:27:00.0], [...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
  def removerChaves(s: String) = s.map(c => if(c == '[') ' ' else c).map(c => if(c == ']') ' ' else c).trim

val conf = new SparkConf(true)
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").setAppName("CasteDate").setMaster("local[*]")
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
   .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
   .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val csc=new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

var input: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
input.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
var dia: SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
var mes: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM")
var ano: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
var horas: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH")
var minutos: SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("mm")

val data=csc.sql("SELECT timecol from smartgrids.analyzer_temp").collect().map(c => removerChaves(c))


import sqlContext.implicits._

val result = data.map(row => {
                         val day = dia.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val month = mes.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val year = ano.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val hour = horas.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val minute = minutos.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                             })

val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("day", 2), ("month", 2), ("year", 4), ("hour", 2), ("minute", 2)))
collection.saveToCassandra("features", "datepart", SomeColumns("day", "month", "year", "hour", "minute"))
sc.stop()
```

Eu criei uma expressão pra remover os brackets `removerChaves` e uso ela no data.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda :) Eu usei a função que criaste  e adaptei de outra forma e funcionou. :)

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar fiz a seguinte alteração ao código

```
val result = data.map(row => {
    val day = dia.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))  
    val month = mes.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))                                       
    val year = ano.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))                                        
    val hour = horas.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))                                     
    val minute = minutos.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))
})
```

Eu testei e funciona.